# UserWarning: CUDA initialization:

Tags: pytorch, cuda, hpc

I have installed Pytorch 1.8.1+cu102 using a virtual environment on a HPC cluster.

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

is giving me the below output

```
UserWarning: CUDA initialization: The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old (found version 10010). Please update your GPU driver by downloading and installing a new version from the URL: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx Alternatively, go to: https://pytorch.org to install a PyTorch version that has been compiled with your version of the CUDA driver. (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:109.)
return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
False
```

What could be wrong ? I am not sure how I can update the driver. My requirements are:

```
torch==1.8.1+cu102
torch-cluster==1.5.9
torch-geometric==1.7.0
```

Comment: "*What could be wrong?*"... Well... The error is pretty clear: "*The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old*"

Comment: As you probably wont be able to update the driver on an HPC Cluster, "Alternatively, go to: https://pytorch.org to install a PyTorch version that has been compiled with your version of the CUDA driver." should be the way forward.

Answer (score -3):

Firstly, you need to check which version you need for Pytorch. You can find the cuda version corresponding to Pytorch in the link below.

https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

After you find the version, you need to check whether the version is available for your GPU device. You can find the list in the link below.

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

If there is no match, you need to change either pytorch requirement or your GPU device.